# SSRS: how to set the value of a property for a cell by Column position?

Tags: reporting-services

I've this table

```
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| header 1 | header 2 | header 3 | header 4 | header 5 |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| text     |  text    |  1       | 17       | 0        |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| text     | text     |  57      | 70       | 5        |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

I'd like to format this table, such as:

- The header be centered
- the first 2 columns be on the left
- the numbers, i.e. the last 3 columns be on the right

Normally, I could just select the header and apply the formatting and do the same for the reaping rows. The problem is that the header itself is just a row coming from the query.

For the header, I've done this:`= If(RowNumber(Nothing) = 1, "Center", "Default")`

For no-headers rows, i.e. any row number > 1, I'd like to be able to format the first 2 columns to Left and the other remaining to the right.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: What is stopping you using your `RowNumber` expression in each column?

Comment: I think I'll need more that just row number.

Comment: Why?  In your original expression, you can just change the `"Default"` part to whatever you need on a per column basis.

Comment: How about something that says in pseudo-code: `if rownumber > 1 and colum = "column1", align to the left` or maybe instead of a column name, a column position. Besides setting the values for the Text Alignment, there are other properties to set. That's why I'm looking for a more general way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you know that you can select multiple columns and apply the same expression or value for any property.

[image]

The only reason I found to avoid set the expression in each column is that you have a lot of reports with multiples tables with this requeriment.

Just use this expression in the `TextAlign` property for the first two columns:

```
=IIF(RowNumber("DataSetName")=1,"Center","Left")
```

And this one for the third, fourth and fifth columns:

```
=IIF(RowNumber("DataSetName")=1,"Center","Right")
```

Replace `DataSetName` by the actual name of yours. It will work if you don't have row groups in your table.

If you are looking for a automatic way to conditionally set this expression, you may want to implement a RDL parser that set the required style in each TablixCell as shown below, but that is out of the SSDT and Report Builder scope.

```
<TablixCell>
    <CellContents>
        <Textbox Name="Column1">
            <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
            <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
            <Paragraphs>
                <Paragraph>
                    <TextRuns>
                        <TextRun>
                            <Value>=Fields!Column1.Value</Value>
                            <Style />
                        </TextRun>
                    </TextRuns>
                    <Style>
                        <TextAlign>=IIF(RowNumber("DataSetName")=1,"Center","Left")</TextAlign>
                    </Style>
                </Paragraph>
            </Paragraphs>
            <rd:DefaultName>Column1</rd:DefaultName>
            <Style>
                <Border>
                    <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                    <Style>Solid</Style>
                </Border>
                <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
            </Style>
        </Textbox>
    </CellContents>
</TablixCell>
```

Let me know if this helps.